# I can not use Google Fonts and WordPress Flutter

Tags: flutter

There is no error when I use Google Fonts alone But when I add WordPress Flutter, I get an error [first photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVaXm.png) & [second photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npXhU.png).

---

```
dependencies:
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4
  flutter_wordpress: ^0.2.1
```

[flutter_wordpress 0.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wordpress/install)

Comment: Have you upgraded your app to null safety? If yes, then try changing sdk to `'>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because `google_fonts: ^2.0.0` uses `http: ^0.13.0` and flutter_wordpress uses `http: ^0.12.1+1` so there is a dependency conflict
so one solution would be to downgrade google fonts to the most compatibe version

which is `google_fonts: ^1.1.2` and that should fix the error.

Also downgrade doesnt mean you are missing on any features the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts/changelog) specifies 2.0.0 has only null safety added.

Comment: Thank you.Yes, my problem is solved. Can I get a WhatsApp number for more help? I had a few questions to make responsive apps

Comment: sorry I do not use whatsapp but you can contact me on twitter @maheshmnj